# Converting an Instant date from a DB Object into localDateTime, but getting a weird way in the future date

Tags: java

This is the Object (store in Postgres) containing the date from a db, I'm trying to convert from Instant date to localDateTime date:

```
public class Event implements Serializable {
    ..
    private Instant plannedStartDate;
```

1. in the database table the column is defined as 'timestamp NULL'
2. in the object is define as Instant

So after instantiating, etc. I do:
    event.getPlannedStartDate().atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC).toLocalDateTime().toString()

I'm expecting a date like: `2018-11-23 05:00:00`
But instead getting this weird date: `{+50864-02-11T08:00}`

Comment: Is UTC actually the right time zone for your use case?

Comment: What is column type in the database? How was `plannedStartDate` loaded from database? --- It is not the conversion to `LocalDateTime` that caused the problem, so please show us the *relevant* code, if you want our help.

Comment: most important, what is the result of `event.getPlannedStartDate()` (**value** and type)?

Comment: result of event.getPlannedStartDate() toString is {+50864-02-11T08:00:00Z}

Comment: result of event.getPlannedStartDate() converted to LocalDateTIme is {+50864-02-11T08:00}

Comment: LocalDateTime plannedStartDate = event.getPlannedStartDate().atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC).toLocalDateTime();

Comment: probably the value of planned start date is wrong, according result of `toString` - probably it is being interpreted as seconds or so, but should be milliseconds (e.g. using `Instant.ofEpochSecond()` instead of `ofEpochMilli()`) - but that part of code was not posted

Comment: I was able resolve this issue as following: LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(events.getPlannedStartDate().getEpochSecond()), ZoneOffset.UTC)